# Modify result of a multiple column query with JOIN

Tags: sql, postgresql

I work with `postgresql 9.1`.

I have two linked tables :
a table events :

```
 eventid |    name    
---------+------------
       1 | event1
       2 | deuxieme
       3 | troisieme3
```

and a table images linked to the events like this :

```
 id |          path          | alt  | eventid | 
----+------------------------+------+---------+
  1 | /something/to/img.jpg  | alt  |       1 |      
  2 | /something/to/img2.jpg | alt2 |       1 |      
  3 | /something/to/img3.jpg | alt3 |       2 |
```

I want to return a list of all the events with the linked paths and alts. So far I used this query :

```
 SELECT events.eventId, events.name, string_agg(distinct images.path, ',') AS paths, string_agg(distinct images.alt, ',') AS alts
    FROM events
    LEFT JOIN images ON images.eventId = events.eventId
    GROUP BY events.eventId;
```

But there is a problem, it returns :

```
 eventid |    name    |                    paths                     |   alts   
---------+------------+----------------------------------------------+----------
       1 | event1     | /something/to/img2.jpg,/something/to/img.jpg | alt,alt2
       2 | deuxieme   | /something/to/img3.jpg                       | alt3
       3 | troisieme3 |                                              |
```

As you can see the paths and the alts aren't in the same order and for the moment there is no way to know which alts and paths are corresponding to the same image. So my question is : is there a way to group them in the result or if it is not possible, how can I render it in the same order? Thanks ;)

Comment: Do you really need the `DISTINCT` part?

Comment: Not in this query, and that's right that it works without it, but in fact my query is longer and there is other tables to JOIN, so I need the distinct.

Comment: there is something not clear in your request. you combine the data into a string (actually 2 strings) and reading the strings you want to be able to match the string components. it looks like you combine the strings to split them later. why don't you just use the data as is?

Comment: @user3683807 The problem is that if alt is unique but the URLs are not, you may get 2 URLs and 3 ALTs after your distincts. If you get that, the order will be broken anyway.

Comment: @Paolo If I don't do that I get the following error : column "images.path" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson : yes that's right, that's why I would prefer to group alts and paths in the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the simplest modification - if you don't want the results on separate rows - would be to just comma separate the values, url,alt,url,alt,... which would make the DISTINCT work on the whole URL/ALT pair at once.

```
SELECT events.eventId, events.name, 
string_agg(distinct images.path || ',' || images.alt, ',') AS images
FROM events
LEFT JOIN images ON images.eventId = events.eventId
GROUP BY events.eventId, events.name;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/a8de4/1).

Comment: Ok thanks! It's works perfectly, even with my other JOIN. One small other additional question : do you personally think that render the result on separate rows would be better suited? (I have several other JOIN in my query).

Comment: @user3683807 If this works for you, I can't see any reason to complicate things :)

Comment: Ok thanks for your time! (I was thinking about performances.)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT events.eventId, events.name, 
       array_to_string(array_agg(images.path order by id), ',') AS paths, 
       array_to_string(array_agg(images.alt  order by id), ',') AS alts
    FROM events
    LEFT JOIN images ON images.eventId = events.eventId
    GROUP BY events.eventId, events.name;
```

Comment: coalesc seems not to be recognized by postgresql 9.1.

Comment: Thanks, it answers to my question but it doesn't work if I add other JOIN so I accepted the other answer, but still +1 for you ;)

Comment: Did you understand the sql you consider "right"? You DO realize that if any value is null (in imagens.path or images.alt), it will not work at all!! I can't see why this will not work with "another join"? Maybe if you explain what you're trying to accomplish, I'll can help you more.